# Edit / extract data before gets to the json parser in a Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, collections

I made a Backbone Collection to manipulate Boards objects from the [4chan API](https://api.4chan.org/boards.json) as follows:

```
var BoardsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Board,   
    url: 'https://api.4chan.org/boards.json',
    sync: function(method, model, options){  
        options.timeout = 10000;  
        options.dataType = "jsonp"; 
        options.crossDomain = true; 
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);   
    }

});
return new BoardsCollection();
```

Because the cross domain error I made a JSONP request to get it work but the JSON that 4chan responds is as follows:

```
{"boards":    
    [{"board":"3","title":"3DCG","ws_board":1,"per_page":15,"pages":11},
     {"board":"a","title":"Anime \u0026 Manga","ws_board":1,"per_page":15,"pages":11}]
```

Is not a valid JSONP because of the "boards" item and the parser of backbone fails with the error "unexpected character :".

So I need a way to edit the response of the server, extract the value from the key "boards" and pass it to the collection for the parsing.

As a side note, I made a little server in node.js that takes the json from 4chan and extracts the value of boards and returns it, with it the collection worked just fine. But I will using this to make a jquery mobile app so I need to connect to the real 4chan API.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't do it without a proxy like node.js or php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with a format of json, but with the fact it is just json, not jsonp. Jsonp is loaded via `<script>` tag, so it needs to be a proper javascript code, it should like `callback({data:'data'})`.

In your case you need to set up a server to proxy requests to 4chan api. If you run it on the same domain, you can use simple XmlHttpRequests. The problem with `boards` top level key is solved then via collection's parse function:

```
parse: function (response) {
    return response.boards;
}
```